# Need Batch script to use Proxy Server

Tags: javascript, web-services, batch-file, proxy

I have a batch script that is supposed to pull data from a webservice via a .js file. When i try and run the script in the environment its designed for i get an error saying it cannot reach the server. I know the environment I'm developing this script for uses proxy settings to access the internet. So my question is how can i make my script use the proxy settings in order to access the internet? I'm not very familiar with batch scripting and have tried a few basic things like ensuring my IE is configured correctly but alas nothing has worked. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is related to how you download a file with the .js file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041886/how-can-i-specify-a-proxy-configuration-using-microsoft-xmlhttp

Comment: the problem comes up before it even attempts to download the file as the batch script is not able to access the web address to the webservice.

Comment: A batch file cannot interact with the internet on its own, you say you go via a js file that presumably does, that's where the issue is. You can use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP + proxycfg in your js to configure the proxy details.